# My Iphone 6 is damaged because of pressure

Tags: iphone

My Iphone 6 was laying on the bed and i wasnt aware of where it was, so i laid down on my bed and my knee was putting a lot of pressure on the screen and the screen cracked and now my iphone is black and has lots if different colors on screen . Is it replaceable? Help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Usually if it's just the screen Apple has a screen replacement program where they would either replace the screen or the entire phone for $79 with the AppleCare coverages or $109 without it.

You could start the process at [Apple's Support Page](https://support.apple.com/iphone/repair/screen-damage)

Answer (score 0):

My friend just took her iPhone 6 to the Apple Store and, out of warranty, they fixed her phone for $120. The screen was uhh... quite.... destroyed.
[image]

Comment: exactly how mine looks